# Parsing string on HTML page

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

I got this string output on a page. its HTML and I need to get it "human readable"
Its stats from a server.

Could you help me getting it a bit more "clear"

The string printed is:

{"result": ["9.7 - CN", "0", "483;0;0", "483", "0;0;0", "off", "50;20", "45550", "0;0;0;0"]}

Is it possible to get it to be:

Version: 9.7 - CN
Speed: 483
Temp/fan 50 20

and so on, any help is appreciated

This must be done client side

I now have this in a html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
const regex = /{.*}/g;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://10.0.0.20:3333', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    var resp = request.responseText;
    var json = regex.exec(resp);
    obj = JSON.parse(json[0]);
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Version: ' + obj.result[0] + ' 
Speed: ' + obj.result[2].split(';')[0] + ' Temp/fan ' + obj.result[6].replace(';', ' ');
  } else {
    console.log('We reached our target server, but it returned an error');
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  console.log('There was a connection error of some sort');
};

request.send();
</script>

<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this comes from php, you could start by using json_decode($thestring) to make it more readable. And print_r or var_dump that.

Comment: Do you want to change this client side or server side? Client side -> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp ; Server side : http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php ; After that use the appropriate array function to iterate over the elements

Answer (score 3):

Using JavaScript:

```
var res = {"result": ["9.7 - CN", "0", "483;0;0", "483", "0;0;0", "off", "50;20", "45550", "0;0;0;0"]} 
var text = 'Version: '+res.result[0]+' Speed: '+ res.result[3]+' Temp/fan '+ res.result[6].replace(';', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
<?php
    $input = '{"result": ["9.7 - CN", "0", "483;0;0", "483", "0;0;0", "off", "50;20", "45550", "0;0;0;0"]}';
    $parsed = json_decode($input, true);
    echo "Version: ".$parsed["result"][0]." Speed: ".explode(";",$parsed["result"][3])[0]." Temp/fan ".str_replace(";"," ",$parsed["result"][6]);   
?>
```

Might not be the prettiest code but you can also do it client-side:

```js
var json = '{"result": ["9.7 - CN", "0", "483;0;0", "483", "0;0;0", "off", "50;20", "45550", "0;0;0;0"]}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Version: '+obj.result[0]+' Speed: '+obj.result[2].split(';')[0]+' Temp/fan '+obj.result[6].replace(';',' ');
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

**Client-side version with AJAX call included:**

(I'm not sure if it's http or https on the URL you provided but give it a try and see if it solves the problem)

```js
const regex = /{.*}/g;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://10.0.0.20:3333', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    var resp = request.responseText;
    var json = regex.exec(resp);
    obj = JSON.parse(json[0]);
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Version: ' + obj.result[0] + ' 
Speed: ' + obj.result[2].split(';')[0] + ' Temp/fan ' + obj.result[6].replace(';', ' ');
  } else {
    console.log('We reached our target server, but it returned an error');
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  console.log('There was a connection error of some sort');
};

request.send();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Also I can't edit the page it's on. Closed code. So I have to get it from 10.0.0.20:3333 is that possible?

Comment: Sure - would you prefer server- or client-side?

Comment: client side. since i cant edit the code in the script that outputs the code. its a microhttp server inside a exe file.
So hte javascript must "get" the other webside. Find that string "result" and then display it. that other code you have should work because it displays what i want, it just doesnt get the remote url.

Comment: I've added an alternative with the ajax-call included to get the content.

Comment: It's not working.

This is the beginning of the raw html output:
<html><body bgcolor="#808080" style="font-family: monospace;">
{"result": ["9.7 - CN", "776", "593;4780;0", "593", "0;0;0", "off", "71;40", "45590", "0;0;0;0"]}<br><br>

Comment: Ok, I've added a regexp to fetch the json-part of the string.

Comment: i edited my initial post. it still doesnt work unfortunately :(

Comment: None. White page

Comment: Ok, if you try Inspect Element (in Chrome) and look at the Console-tab you should get some sort of message. I tried this code but changed the URL at my private playground now and it works fine: https://grimsgaard.priv.no/test.php

Comment: Failed to load http://10.0.0.20:3333/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: In that case - this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3076414/6395616

Comment: that i understood even less of!

Comment: Sorry :) The problem is the source of the data is not allowing you to fetch the statistics you need. So the problem is actually with the source. But there may be ways to work around that and those alternatives is covered in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Espen.
I ended up using the chrome plugin: UtvidelseAllow-Control-Allow-Origin: * to achieve the load of the page.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Good luck! 